# why the compilation is must in datastage before run?

Tags: datastage

Is it necessary to compile a job every time when we are trying to run it? I have not modified anything in job but still every time when i am trying to run it is asking to compile. why is it necessary? what is happening while compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Compiling generates the binaries and scripts that run the job. Compiling before running a job is required. Once compiled, you can run the job over again and again without compiling if the job ran successfully. For Job aborts/failures, a recompile is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge weakness of DataStage.   Recompiling unchanged code is an extreme nuisance at best.   Product owners of DataStage should eliminate this curse of an ongoing problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.